# Locale not changing in FirebaseMessagingService

Tags: android, push-notification, notifications

My app language is turkish and device language is english. I can set the language turkish with code below smoothly. All application pages change properly.

```
private void changeLang(String locale) {
        Resources res = this.getResources();
        DisplayMetrics dm = res.getDisplayMetrics();
        Configuration conf = res.getConfiguration();
        conf.setLocale(new Locale(locale.toLowerCase()));
        res.updateConfiguration(conf, dm);

        Configuration newConfig = new Configuration();
        newConfig.locale = new Locale(locale.toLowerCase());
        onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    }
```

But when Im sending a push notification, Notification text still english. I see the locale still english when Im debug.

```
    public class MyFirebaseMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService {

        @Override
        public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
             Locale current = getResources().getConfiguration().locale;
            //current not change, always english
        }
    }
```

Why the service cannot get true locale, always get device locale.